# Using SoC and electrical power output to estimate thermal losses in a battery

Tags: batteries

I am modeling a battery and want to calculate the absolute hottest it could get under given load conditions, assuming adiabatic conditions. This means I need \$Q_{heat}\$ to solve \$Q_{heat} = m C_p \Delta T \$

If I have a battery and know its nominal energy rating, \$E_{nominal}\$, its state of charge, \$SoC\$, and how much electrical energy has been removed, \$E_{electrical,out}\$, is there a simple first-order approximation of thermal energy losses?

Is it as easy as the difference between the two? I.e.:

\$Q_{heat} = SoC * E_{nominal} - E_{electrical,out}\$

Comment: If no heat is transferred away, the temperature will keep rising until it melts. Clearly that won't happen in reality so, you have to figure this out based on what constitutes the losses when supplying current to the load.

Comment: @Andyaka that's not correct that a battery must continually heat until melting, I'm not sure what would make you say that. The heat comes from the inefficiency in the chemical process, so at a certain point the battery is efficient enough that under certain conditions it could never exceed a given threshold temperature.

Comment: I said it because you said "assuming no heat is transferred away".

Comment: @Andyaka Yes, it's adiabatic. You're missing some fundamental physics here about heat and temperature rise. Perhaps you're making an assumption which I can clear up by refining the question?

Comment: Also, this is a bit of a distraction, since the question is not what happens to the battery, but whether a first order model for thermal losses is possible knowing the cell, the cell's SoC, and the electrical energy out.

Comment: Tough question, and hard to answer the way it was posed. I don't know why you need this kind of a model, but the way I would do it is by finding the ESR of the battery as well as its thermal capacity (which is fairly hard to know accurately, but not impossible), then calculate the energy loss at a certain current, and then the temperature rise.
 I have a similar practical problem ahead of me where I want to bury lithium battery underground to keep it from freezing temperatures, and using its own loss, as well as of the electronics added to raise the temperature that is "more to its liking".

Comment: Also, since the ground will be absorbing a significant amount of heat, I am not too worried being 100% accurate in my estimates, so it's not exactly like the problem you have, but I still have to make sure things don't get too hot.

Comment: @EdinFifić I would like this model because I'd like to have an upper bound on how much heat needs to be transferred away. As we both know, cells have strict upper temperature limits, so if the adiabatic scenario shows that a cell's thermal mass can absorb enough heat such that the temperature never rises above critical temp, then we can be sure the real system does not need cooling, either. And, alternatively, if the temp bounds will be exceeded we can calculate how much cooling we need on average to stay within safe limits.

Comment: @EdinFifić I think we actually have very similar real-world needs: a battery pack which naturally has poor heat transfer. I'm working on calculating what worst case looks like so in these kind of situations we can figure out if we even need to care about cooling. I'll do some tests as well to confirm, but it would be useful to know what we can infer from manuf. datasheets.

Comment: @KennSebesta  I tend to first look for simplest solutions and calculations with less precision to get a ballpark figure first, and then go deeper if necessary. The good thing about lithium cells in general is that they have relatively low losses which enable the heat to be transferred THROUGH and usually out of them fast enough in most scenarios, but large currents and an enclosed environment with a high thermal resistance can quickly lead to a disaster.
 I might at first simply just use the fact that lithium cells generally have about 99% charging/discharging efficiency, and add ESR in.